# Twitter Status Update: in_reply_to_status_id is null always

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am using PHP Twitter API to update status on Twitter.I have retrieved the in_reply_to_status_id parameter from Tweet.When i tried to reply to that tweet i have passed status and in_reply_to_status_id parameters to twitter post function.But in curl response it always shows in_reply_to_status_id parameter as null.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue by passing id parameter to reply_to_status_id while posting reply to Twitter posts